# Website hosted Ubuntu 20.04 VPS server DHCP need?

Tags: 20.04, dhcp, webserver

I have LEMP stack VPS. This server run Ubuntu 20.04. Do I need enable DHCP?

If I disabled DHCP is it affect hosted WordPress sites?

Comment: No. You do not need DHCP on a web server. Are you having connection problems?

Comment: I don't have any connectivity issue. CSF inform me to remove DHCP for security reasons

Comment: DHCP is not installed by default on any Ubuntu installation and it would be illogical to have it on a VPS. If it is installed on your server, then it makes sense to remove it.